# How to count sheets of another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I try to write a function to get the count of sheet of another workbook. But, below code, the debug, at wb.Sheets.Count, raises an error. Please help me to return the count of sheet of another workbook (in wb reference).

```
Function GetSheetCount(XlsFileName As String) As Integer
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook

    'Dim ws As Worksheet
    'Dim i As Integer
    'i = 0

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(XlsFileName)

    'For Each ws In wb.Sheets
       'i = i + 1
    'Next ws

    GetSheetCount = wb.Sheets.Count'i

    'wb.Close False
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code essentially works per the abbreviated example below. Can you specify the error to better debug your issue?

**Code**

[image: code]

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you. After adding a sub of test, it returns correct value. I tested it as a formula, so it raised an error #VALUE in cell. Can you convert it into a function for using in sheet interface as a formula?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible (happy to be corrected on that!). There are strict limitations on custom functions. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel